# Having trouble with Array.each getting errors like: 'syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input'

Tags: arrays, ruby, syntax, each, keyword

I'm pretty new on Ruby, as I'm learning it as part of the Stockfighter program (https://www.stockfighter.io). I'm trying to link up with the API they have there, and I've had no problems with that in the past, so I think my problem has to do with my `getAverage` function, which is supposed to take an array of values, add the values together, and then divide by the length of the array so I have an average price per share of this simulated stock market. Specifically, I'm getting errors like these:

```
/Users/Kai/Dropbox/Kai/Stockfighter/level_three_selling.rb:41: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
        averageArr.each do |i|
                          ^
/Users/Kai/Dropbox/Kai/Stockfighter/level_three_selling.rb:51: warning: else without rescue is useless
/Users/Kai/Dropbox/Kai/Stockfighter/level_three_selling.rb:53: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

And I've looked through my code for errors, but can't find any. I think I just need a second pair of eyes to find what's missing. Maybe I'm missing an `end` somewhere or my syntax is wrong. I've never had this issue before, and I've already dug around a little on StackOverflow and other places, but most of the other errors people have that are similar to mine give confusing answers that make no sense to a newbie like myself.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

apikey = 'MY_KEY_IS_HERE'
venue = "VENUEX"
stock = "FOOBAR"

base_url = "https://api.stockfighter.io/ob/api"

account = "MY_ACCOUNT_IS_HERE"

averageArr = []

counter = 0


def getQuote(stock, venue, account)

    response = HTTParty.get("https://api.stockfighter.io/ob/api/venues/#{venue}/stocks/#{stock}/quote")

    orderbook = response.parsed_response

    puts orderbook["ok"]

    return orderbook["last"]
    puts orderbook["lastTrade"]

end


def getAverage(stock, venue, account)

    averageArr.push(getQuote(stock, venue, account))
    counter ++

    if counter >= 5

        sum = 0

        #FIRST ERROR POINTS TO HERE
        averageArr.each do |i|
            sum += i
        end

        return sum/5

    else

        return 'WAITING'

    #SECOND ERROR POINTS HERE
    end
#THIRD ERROR POINTS HERE
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Part of the problem is that your code is not well formatted and hence it has blocks that are incomplete.  If you indent and format your code, you will see the problem

Comment: Ok thanks! Sorry if I was vague, this is my first question I've asked on SO. I'll try running through it one more time

Comment: Is there an issue with data types on my `averageArr.each do |i|` block? Maybe my `getQuote` function returns a string and not an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`++` is not a Ruby operator.  You should use

```
counter += 1
```

in the second line of `getAverage` method.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe that's the issue. I'm more into JS, so I must've just put ++ out of habit. This fixed all of my problems.